# Object reference not set to an instance of an object VB.net Exception

Tags: vb.net

I made a simple for loop in VB.net to check every textbox in my webpage, set empty textbox value to 0 and it looks like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 62 Step 1
    Dim value0 As String = "textbox" + i.ToString()
    tb0 = PlaceHolder1.FindControl(value0)

    If tb0.Text = String.Empty Then
        tb0.Text = "0"
    End If                
Next
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Happens here: `If tb0.Text = String.Empty Then`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `FindControl` will return null if the specified control name does not exist.

You may add extra condition to check if `tb0` is null or not.

```
IF  tb0 Is NOT Nothing
    If tb0.Text = String.Empty Then
        tb0.Text = "0"
    End If     
END IF
```